# PC32 relocation instructions in eh_frame

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I am trying to understand code models used for creating object files. I have two sample files which I am using for trying out different code models:

```
// sample_header.h
extern int num;

void func();

// sample_header.cc
#include "sample_header.h"

int num = 10;

void func() {
    num += 10;
}
```

I compiled it using this command: `g++ -mcmodel=large -c sample_header.cc -o sample_header.o`
And `readelf -r sample_header.o` produces this:

```
Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x1d0 contains 3 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000011  00050000001d R_X86_64_GOTPC64  0000000000000000 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ + 9
00000000001e  000300000019 R_X86_64_GOTOFF64 0000000000000000 num + 0
00000000002e  000300000019 R_X86_64_GOTOFF64 0000000000000000 num + 0

Relocation section '.rela.eh_frame' at offset 0x218 contains 1 entry:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000020  000200000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text + 0
```

The `.text` relocations are of 64 bit relocations types, which is expected, but the `eh_frame` contains some relocations of small-code model style. I have two questions:

1. Why is an `eh_frame` their in the first place? Isn't it supposed to be only for exception handling purpose ?(and this simple file does not have any exception handling).
2. Why is it generating PC32 instructions and how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is an `eh_frame` their in the first place? Isn't it supposed to be only for exception handling purpose?

No. The `.eh_frame` is also needed for debugger to be able to unwind the stack. Without `.eh_frame`, and without `-fno-omit-frame-poiunter` (`-fomit-frame-pointer` is the default with optimization), you wouldn't be able to tell where your program crashed.

> Why is it generating PC32 instructions and how to change it?

It shouldn't. Sounds like a bug in GCC (I used `Debian 12.2.0-14` and got the same result).

For contrast, `Debian clang version 14.0.6` produces:

```
Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x168 contains 2 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
00000000000d  00040000001d R_X86_64_GOTPC64  0000000000000000 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ + 9
00000000001a  000500000019 R_X86_64_GOTOFF64 0000000000000000 num + 0

Relocation section '.rela.eh_frame' at offset 0x198 contains 1 entry:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000020  000200000018 R_X86_64_PC64     0000000000000000 .text + 0
```

In general, very few people have binaries which require `-mcmodel=large`, and so support for it is not well tested.